# What do you mean #classname in css

Tags: css

My project contains the following code but am not getting #M,#D  and so on.I am new to CSS

```
        <div id="DivM" class="M" style="display: none;">
        </div>
        <div id="DivB" class="B" style="display: none;">
        </div>
        <div id="DivD" class="D" style="display: none;">
        </div>
        <div id="DivL" class="L" style="display: none;">
        </div>
        <div id="DivO" class="O" style="display: none;">
        </div>
```

and CSS

```
#M {background: url(/images/M.png) no-repeat;width: 148px;height:90px;top: 18px;left:3px;outline:none;list-style:none;}
#B {background: url(/images/B.png) no-repeat;width: 292px;height:90px;top: 0;left: 0;outline:none;list-style:none;}
#D {background: url(/images/D.png) no-repeat;width: 158px;height:90px;top:18px;left:78px;outline:none;}
#L {background: url(/images/L.png) no-repeat;width: 158px;height: 50px;top:82px;left:22px;outline:none;list-style:none;}
#O {background: url(/images/O.png) no-repeat;width: 158px;height:90px;top:37px;left:36px;outline:none;list-style:none;}
```

Comment: The hashtag "#" select the ID of the element e.g. "#DivM" whereas to select the class you would use the . selector e.g. ".M"

Comment: Is it not possible to have #classname.But when the div are loaded(page is loaded) the images are also seen on the page.

Comment: I got it .It was my Mistake.i should use .classname for class and #id for id.Thank u all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on Classes and IDs http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Putting an # before means that your trying to add a style for an **ID** and not a class.
So if you want to use the classes of your Divs you should change your CSS to:

```
.M {background: url(/images/M.png) no-repeat;width: 148px;height:90px;top: 18px;left:3px;outline:none;list-style:none;}
.B {background: url(/images/B.png) no-repeat;width: 292px;height:90px;top: 0;left: 0;outline:none;list-style:none;}
.D {background: url(/images/D.png) no-repeat;width: 158px;height:90px;top:18px;left:78px;outline:none;}
.L {background: url(/images/L.png) no-repeat;width: 158px;height: 50px;top:82px;left:22px;outline:none;list-style:none;}
.O {background: url(/images/O.png) no-repeat;width: 158px;height:90px;top:37px;left:36px;outline:none;list-style:none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those styles won't work, `#M` targets elements with the `id` of `M`, `.M` targets elements with the `class` of `M`. This would work:

```
.M { ... }
.B { ... }
.D { ... }
.L { ... }
.O { ... }
```

Or this:

```
#DivM { ... }
#DivB { ... }
#DivD { ... }
#DivL { ... }
#DivO { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

`#` is for selecting by the `id` attribute, not the `class` attribute (that would be `.`).

Answer (score 0):

The CSS won't have any effect. In CSS `#` is an ID selector, while `.` is a classname selector. So for example:

`<div id="mydiv"></div>` should be referenced with  `#mydiv {  }`

Where as `<div class="mydiv"></div>` should be referenced with `.mydiv`.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` is used for id, you should use `.` for classes:

```
.M {background: url(/images/M.png) no-repeat;width: 148px;height:90px;top: 18px;left:3px;outline:none;list-style:none;}
.B {background: url(/images/B.png) no-repeat;width: 292px;height:90px;top: 0;left: 0;outline:none;list-style:none;}
.D {background: url(/images/D.png) no-repeat;width: 158px;height:90px;top:18px;left:78px;outline:none;}
.L {background: url(/images/L.png) no-repeat;width: 158px;height: 50px;top:82px;left:22px;outline:none;list-style:none;}
.O {background: url(/images/O.png) no-repeat;width: 158px;height:90px;top:37px;left:36px;outline:none;list-style:none;}
```